# Inverse Kinematics from Python

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I access the inverse kinematics solver from Python (with or without using moveit)? The tutorial on the moveit website does not seem to be up to date.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107381/inverse-kinematics-from-python/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2013-12-05

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2013-12-06**:
Thanks. Could you post your code? I've a hard time finding the right Python commands to use. In particular, what arguments are you providing to rospy.ServiceProxy(...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is kind of hacky, but I've just been using the /compute_ik service call while running move_group, both from python and C++. I'm hoping that there's a simple and lighter-weight solution ...

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ah, got it. This is a good example: https://github.com/chili-epfl/hoap3_write/blob/master/scripts/sample_reachable.py

---

Originally posted by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) with karma: 529 on 2013-12-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1